# Как сделать что б функция проверяла себя каждую минуту?

Tags: python, функции, async-await

Существует код для ds-бота на python. С момента начала работы функции захвата сообщений. Затем о наложении запрета и выдаче времени. И 3 функции, которые должны включаться каждую минуту и проверять, прошло ли время запрета. Как я могу заставить его отзываться каждую минуту? желательно асинхронный вызов, если это невозможно, то можно просто. Все, что я ищу, не имеет значения.

```
async def unban_func(message):
connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()

time_now_h = datetime.now().hour
time_now_m = datetime.now().minute

with connect:
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT H_to_unbun FROM users")
    time_unban_h = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT M_to_unbun FROM users")
    time_unban_m = cursor.fetchall()

    time_unban_h_mass = []
    time_unban_m_mass = []

for g in time_unban_h:
    time_unban_h_mass.append(g[0])
for g in time_unban_m:
    time_unban_m_mass.append(g[0])

for h in time_unban_h_mass:
    for m in time_unban_m_mass:
        index_h = time_unban_h_mass.index(h)
        index_m = time_unban_m_mass.index(m)
        if index_h == index_m:
            if int(h) == int(time_now_h) and int(m) == int(time_now_m):
                with connect:
                    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT id FROM users WHERE H_to_unbun = {h} AND M_to_unbun = {m}""")
                    message_author_id = cursor.fetchall()
                    cursor.execute(f"SELECT roles FROM users WHERE  id = {message_author_id}")
                    mass_roles = cursor.fetchall()

                ban_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="ban")

                mass_roles_sort = mass_roles[0][0].split(' ')
                mass_roles_sort.pop()

                for t in mass_roles_sort:
                    g = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=t)
                    await message.author.add_roles(g)

                await message.author.remove_roles(ban_role)
                cursor.execute(f"""UPDATE users SET warning = {1} WHERE id = {message_author_id}""")
                connect.commit()
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Это русскоязычная версия Stack Overflow, я думаю было бы лучше перевести ваш вопрос на русский.

Comment: И надо бы на английском лучше писать. Или не писать вообще. Или писать совсем простыми короткими фразами. Так как написанное понять невозможно, если читать с позиции иностранца (а читать угадывая, что там на русском было, смысла не несёт, если можно русский иметь).

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
t=0
local_time = 60
time.sleep(local_time)
t=1
if t==1:
    unban_func
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).